# Ajax response with multiple form not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, responsive

I have a problem with working on multiple forms from an AJAX response that didn't working for me.

Here is the main AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#routine').click(function(){
    var ids = $.map($('#table').bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
    return row.StaffId
    });
    id=ids[0];
    if(!ids[0])
          msg("Please Select a Staff");
    else{
        $("#loginScreen").show();
        msg('Please Wait...');
        $.ajax({url: "staff.php?action=getroutine&SID="+id,
        type:'GET',
        success: function(s){
        msgclose();
        $("#contd").html(s);
        },
        error: function(e){
        msg('Error Processing your Request!!');
        }
     });
    }           
  });
});
```

And the staff.php file is as follows:

```
for($d=0;$d<6;$d++)
        {
        echo"<tr>
                <form class='form-horizontal' role='form' id='d".($d+1)."' onsubmit='javascript: return false;'>
                <td>".$days[$d]."</td><input type='hidden' id='day".($d+1)."' value='".$days[$d]."'>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class1' name='class1' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class1' name='secclass1'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class1' name='subclass1'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class2' name='class2' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class2' name='secclass2'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class2' name='subclass2'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class3' name='class3' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class3' name='secclass3'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class3' name='subclass3'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class4' name='class4' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class4' name='secclass4'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class4' name='subclass4'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class5' name='class5' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class5' name='secclass5'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class5' name='subclass5'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class6' name='class6' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class6' name='secclass6'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class6' name='subclass6'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class7' name='class7' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class7' name='secclass7'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class7' name='subclass7'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class='form-control' id='".$days[$d]."class8' name='class8' onchange='getComb(this)'>
                        <option value='' selected>CLASS</option>
                        <option value='V'>Class V</option>
                        <option value='VI'>Class VI</option>
                        <option value='VII'>Class VII</option>
                        <option value='VIII'>Class VIII</option>
                        <option value='IX'>Class IX</option>
                        <option value='X'>Class X</option>
                        <option value='XI'>Class XI</option>
                        <option value='XII'>Class XII</option>
                    </select>

                    <select class='form-control' id='sec".$days[$d]."class8' name='secclass8'>
                        <option value='' selected>SEC</option>
                    </select>                   

                    <select class='form-control' id='sub".$days[$d]."class8' name='subclass8'>
                        <option value='' selected>SUBJECT</option>
                    </select>                   
                </td>                   
            <td>
            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Save Change</button>
            </td>
            </form></tr>";
        }
        echo"</tbody>
    </table>
</div>";
```

Now I have 6 form IDs `d1` to `d6` and in the main page I have the following functions for each form:

```
$(document).on('submit','#d1',function(){
    var formData = $('#d1').serializeObject();
    msg("FormData="+formData);
});
$(document).on('submit','#d2',function(){
    var formData = $('#d2').serializeObject();
    msg("FormData="+formData);
});
$(document).on('submit','#d3',function(){
    var formData = $('#d3').serializeObject();
    msg("FormData="+formData);
});

$(document).on('submit','#d4',function(){
    var formData = $('#d4').serializeObject();
    msg("FormData="+formData);
});
$(document).on('submit','#d5',function(){
    var formData = $('#d5').serializeObject();
    msg("FormData="+formData);
});
$(document).on('submit','#d6',function(){
    var formData = $('#d6').serializeObject();
    msg("FormData="+formData);
});
```

The SUBMIT button for each form is supposed to be showing a message with form data but they are not working. Help me please.